# $5$ different marbles are placed in $5$ different boxes randomly.Find the probability that exactly two boxes remain empty.

Tags: probability

$5$ different marbles are placed in $5$ different boxes randomly.Find the probability that exactly two boxes remain empty.Given each box can hold any number of marbles.

I counted total number of cases as $5^5$ but i could not count the favorable number of cases.Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note *distinct* marbles, *distinct* boxes.

You have computed total ways of $5^5$ correctly.

For favorable ways, use inclusion-exclusion, exactly two empty = exactly three filled

Ways exactly $3$ filled = $\dbinom{5}{3}\left[3^5 - \dbinom{3}{2}2^5 + \dbinom{3}{1}1^5\right] = 1500$

Comment: What is the book answer ?

Comment: Yes i will get correct answer from this,i am very sorry

Comment: $\frac{1500}{5^5}=\frac{12}{25}$,thank you sir.@true blue anil

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle, and also search for sites with worked examples.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_3$ is number of ways to fill $5$ Marbles into $3$ boxes such that no box is Empty. So
$$T_3=3^5-\left[\binom{3}{1}T_2+\binom{3}{2}T_1\right]$$ where $T_2$ is Number of ways to fill $5$ Marbles into $2$ boxes such that no box is empty and $T_1$ is number of ways to fill $5$ marbles into one box such that it is not empty. Trivially $T_1=1$.So

$$T_2=2^5-\left[\binom{2}{1}T_1\right]$$ where  So $T_2=30$ and Hence $T_3=243-93=150$

Hence Total ways such that Exactly two are Empty is $$\binom{5}{3}*150=1500$$

Comment: you have overcounted 30,correct is 1500.