# About marbles and empty boxes.

Tags: probability

My explanation is rather long, so let me start with my questions:

### The Questions

Question 1: Can I apply the method used in solution A1 on problem B? If yes, how?

Question 2: I kind of struggle to know when and when not to use inclusion-exclusion. Anybody guidelines, tips or tricks?

### The problems

I'm working on the following problem:

Suppose 5 marbles are placed in 5 boxes at random. Find the probability p that exactly 1 of the boxes is empty.

Solution for exactly ***one*** box empty (solution A1):

$$P(a)={{5.4.10.3!} \over 5^5}  = {48 \over 125} = 0,384$$

Completely makes sense.

Solution for exactly ***two*** boxes empty (solution B): see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459044/5-different-marbles-are-placed-in-5-different-boxes-randomly-find-the-probab/3792032#3792032)

$$T_3 = {3^5} - {3\choose1}T_1-{3\choose2}.T_2$$

with $$T_1=1$$
and $$T_2=2^5-{2\choose1}.T_1$$

$$==> T3 = {5\choose3}.150 = 1500$$

giving as final result: $$ P(a)={T_3\over5^5}={1500\over{5^5}} = 0.48 $$
$$ $$

so, here we use the inclusion-exclusion method. Still makes a lot of sense.

Actually we can even use the inclusion-exclusion method for problem 1A (solution A2):

$$T_4 = 4^5 -{4\choose3}.T_1 - {4\choose2}.T_2-{4\choose1}.T_3$$

with

$$T_1 = 3^5-{3\choose1}.T_1 - {3\choose2}.T2 = 150$$
$$T_2 = 2^5-{2\choose11}.T_1 = 30$$
$$T_3 = 1 $$

$$==> T_4=240$$

$$ $$
$$P(a) = {T_4\over5^5}={{{5\choose4}. 240}\over{5^5}}=0,384$$

$$ $$

### The Questions (repeat from above)

Question 1: Can I apply the method used in solution A1 on problem B? If yes, how?

Question 2: I kind of struggle to know when and when not to use inclusion-exclusion. Anybody guidelines, tips or tricks?

Thanks,

Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exact two case you can use a similar argument as well

First choose the two boxes to be empty: ${5\choose 2}=10$

Then the unsymmetrical part becomes a bit more complicated. In the one empty case all things are symmetric and can have only $(1,1,1,2)$ up to rearrangement but in the two empty case you can have $(1,1,3)$ or $(1,2,2)$ up to rearrangement so you need to add them up.

$${3\choose1}\cdot{5\choose3}\cdot{2\choose1}+{3\choose 1}\cdot{5\choose1}\cdot{4\choose2}$$

The total result is then

$${10\cdot(3\cdot10\cdot2+3\cdot5\cdot6)\over 5^5}={12\over 25}$$

For each problem, there is usually both a solution that uses the inclusion-exclusion principle and also a solution that adds discrete cases up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome.